# running a docker container on upstart on Amazon Linux isn't working

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, upstart

I'm trying to get my container to run on startup using upstart.

As the tutorial said - I created /etc/init/nginx_server.conf

```
description "Nginx docker"
author "Me"
start on filesystem and started docker
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
script
  /usr/bin/docker run -d -p 80:80 test_server
end script
```

Running of latest Amazon linux (`amzn-ami-hvm-2015.03.0.x86_64-gp2`)

The container isn't running at all (running `docker ps -a` doesn't show it at all)

Comment: Provide an actual image to the run target ? There's no `test_server` container in the docker registry.

Comment: When I run it in command line (after the machine is up) it works. I'm not following what you are trying to say...

Comment: [New to docker](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/) ? What's the `test_server` image ? Where does this come from ? Nothing of this kind is [available in the docker registry](https://registry.hub.docker.com/search?q=test_server&searchfield=). Past your commands and their output when you do this without upstart. Past `sudo docker images` output and `sudo docker ps -a` too.

Comment: It's my own local container of a locally built image

Comment: Ok then... Next time some precision of this kind could bring some context to your question.

Comment: Wow...Amazon Linux still uses upstart?!?

Comment: You have also an option of using `docker run --restart=always -d IMAGEID` to have the container autostart during reboot.

Comment: @Danielt. - it worked! thanks (I think I can't accept this as an answer because I asked a different question - but YOU did help me!!!

Comment: What name did you use for `IMAGEID`?

Comment: Michael Hampton - Amazon Linux is based on EL6, which used upstart.

Answer (score 2):

On Amazon Linux, the Docker daemon is started with an init.d script, not an Upstart script. In your Upstart script you're trying to signal the startup when the docker service starts (`..started docker`). This will only work if the docker init script is an Upstart script.

You can add `initctl emit docker-started` to the docker init.d script and then trigger your Upstart service config file with that event (ie. `start on docker-started`)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do a 'docker run' from the upstart, what you should do is create a container from a docker image, and then do 'docker start' in upstart. If you check /var/log/messages you will probably see something like:

```
init: test_server main process (6570) terminated with status 1
init: test_server respawning too fast, stopped
```

To work around it, try running:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 test_server
```

You will get the container id as an output:

```
a64db8e1cca5
```

Then, put in your upstart file:

```
description "Nginx docker"
start on filesystem and started docker
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
script
  /usr/bin/docker start -a a64db8e1cca5
end script
```

Comment: You can give your container a name with `--name <name>` when using `docker run` and refer to it in other subcommands instead of using the container hash ID.

Comment: Yes, you can, although I answered purposely this way, that it's clearly obvious what's container and what is an image. But still thanks for the comment.

Comment: Why would you not be able to issue `docker run` from upstart since it's basically a create + start action ? I believe you simply need to remove the `-d` option.

Comment: wait. When I do a docker run, it stays persistent in the FS of the host?

Comment: @Boaz Yes unless you pass the `--rm` option.

Comment: well. It didn't help. I had it run with --name as @XavierLucas suggested, and now I have it Exited(0) when running `docker ps -a`. Nothing seems docker related other than `IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready` (which I don't use)
(The exited 0 is after a machine restart)