# Amazon Linux 17.09 init.d script not starting when Docker does

Tags: amazon-ec2, init.d, amazon-linux

I'm probably missing something really silly, but does anyone know why this init script isn't running when Docker starts on Amazon Linux 17.09?

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          replicated-docker
# Required-Start:    docker
# Required-Stop:     docker
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: send upstart signal after starting docker
# Description:       docker needs to run before some upstart services can run
### END INIT INFO

_status() {
    printf "replicated-docker: %s, %s, %s\n" \
        "$(initctl status replicated)" \
        "$(initctl status replicated-ui)" \
        "$(initctl status replicated-operator)"
}

case "$1" in
    start|restart|reload)
        initctl emit replicated-docker --no-wait
    ;;

    stop)
    ;;

    status)
        _status
    ;;

    *)
        printf "Usage: /etc/init.d/replicated-docker {start|stop|status|reload|restart}\n"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

The goal here is to trigger an upstart service whenever Docker starts. Essentially, I'd like to do what's described in [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/755579/465347), except without having to edit the docker init.d script. Automated editing of someone else's init.d script seems like a great way to break things, after all.

I've ensured the permissions match everything else in `/etc/init.d/`, it's been added with `chkconfig --add replicated-docker`, and shows up in `service --status-all`.

And of course, it works when I run the script manually or through `sudo service replicated-docker start`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess just adding script into /etc/init.d/ is not enough, it needs to be referenced in relevant /etc/rcx.d/.